# Installing fonts to Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, cs6

I have fonts on a CD and I want ot load them into Illustrator CS6 so that they will be permanently available when I am working in Illustrator.

Comment: You install fonts on the operating system not in Illustrator...

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you should install fonts on your OS, not a specific program. You can make your fonts available to Illustrator without installing them on your OS though.

From [Illustrator Help / Fonts](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/fonts.html):

> In addition to the fonts installed on your system, you can also create the following folders and use fonts installed in them:
>
> **Windows**  Program Files/Common Files/Adobe/Fonts
>
> **Mac OS**  Library/Application Support/Adobe/Fonts